# How to add custom loader in iphone

Tags: iphone, customization, uiactivityindicatorview

I am developing an application where i lazy load some content on UIView.While the content is getting ready i want to show a loader on view.I would like to have a custom loaded rather then using iOS's `UIActivityIndicatorView` instance.Is there a straight forward way to do this please help.

Comment: then use MBProgressHUD...https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have post a link below it is a very nice custom loader .and it is very nice animation and with view 
so please check it . i have worked its working very fine.

https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Thanks